# Geocoding Google API rate limit?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-geocoding-api

**What is geocoding call/rate call/limit - how many request per second can be done without deny?**

I was read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) but it is enigmatic - tells about rate but not shows the number.

> Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the
>   service.

I developer [console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) there is nothing too but it enforce some limit.

Comment: [**10 requests per second**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits) (you may assume that this also applies to non-business-customers)

Comment: Thank you for hint I will speed up limiter to 10 r/s to test it - it should be the same since after some 10 api response with deny.

Answer (score 0):

In the new console go to "APIs & auth" > "Geocoding API" > "Quota"
The Per-User Limit is not defined but you have 2,500 requests/day max.
In this page, quota info are in real time.

Comment: Call/rate is **defined** but not specified and I want to learn it. At least API has such call/rate defined since API has such feature :)